# LocationManager requestLocationUpdates not working

Tags: android

I Have This Creepy problem. i am trying to get the location of my emulator. it working fine when i get the location of my emulator. but when i change my location coordinates nothing happens. `gps` is working fine.

Here is my code

**Main.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {
TextView tvStatus;
LocationManager lm;
boolean gpsEnabled;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Log.d("", "GPS is Active");
        Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        tvStatus.setText(l.getLatitude()+" , "+l.getLongitude());
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                new LocationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1,
                            Bundle arg2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
                        tvStatus.setText("GPS ENABLED: " + gpsEnabled
                                + "\nLatitude: " + arg0.getLatitude()
                                + "\nLongitude: " + arg0.getLongitude());
                    }
                });
    }

}

    }
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.enabelinglocationprovider"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="5"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.enabelinglocationprovider.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: is location related services are turn on in that device?

Comment: Ya, gps is enabled. one more thing. i have been switching my workspace in eclipse. and now when i restart my emulator it is working fine.

Comment: When i Switch my workspace  does the emulator got disconnected ?

Answer (score 7):

Samsung phones have this problem. There is  hack to this. You need to kick the locationmanager on the butt to get the latest location from the maps cache.

```
God.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
                }
            });
    currentLocation = God.locationManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Call `getLastKnownLocation` after kicking the `requestLocationUpdates` with 0's.

Comment: I also had to do this for Nexus 5 with 5.1.1 Android version

Comment: What does God have to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

It happens with emulators, try rebooting the emulator.

Or, close both eclipse and emulator and start both again