# how to keep redrawing the polyline and markers when locationmanager gives new location on google maps api for android

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

The code works fine first time round, but when locationManager requests a update it doesn't redraw the markers or the polylines when the location changes but the little blue gps circle on it moves by it self and thats it. I want to know how you could get it to change the markers and polylines from the google maps every time the user moves to a new location

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements RoutingListener {
GoogleMap map;
LatLng User;
LatLng end;
Marker user;
Marker END;



/**
 * This activity loads a map and then displays the route and pushpins on it.
 */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    try {
        if (map == null) {
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().
                    findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            map = fm.getMap();
            if (map != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000, 0, (android.location.LocationListener) this);
    if(locationManager!=true){
        onLocationChanged(myLocation);
    }

}

private void onLocationChanged(Location myLocation) {
    user.remove();
    END.remove();
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    end = new LatLng(51.493873, -3.18175);

    User = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    Marker user = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
            position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("you").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue)));

    Marker END = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
            position(end).title("Other User").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green)));

    map.moveCamera((CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(User)));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    Routing routing = new Routing(Routing.TravelMode.WALKING);
    routing.registerListener(this);
    routing.execute(User,end);
}



@Override
public void onRoutingFailure() {
    // The Routing request failed
}

@Override
public void onRoutingStart() {
    // The Routing Request starts
}

@Override
public void onRoutingSuccess(PolylineOptions mPolyOptions, Route route) {
    PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    polyOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
    polyOptions.width(10);
    polyOptions.addAll(mPolyOptions.getPoints());
    map.addPolyline(polyOptions);
}
```

}

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, one thing I am wondering is.. if the onLocationChanged got called at all when you change your location?

Comment: does it not get called automatically when location changes

Comment: huh.. it sounds like a problem regarding to the `requestLocationUpdates`.. which [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700755/locationmanager-requestlocationupdates-not-working) might be the solution?

Comment: Sorry about this but how would I implement that then in my code because I'm not sure how that would work

Comment: I basically want the polylines and markers redrawn every 5 seconds when location changes but it's not happening with the code at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You are only listening when the user has changed location. If you want redraw it every five seconds regardless if the user has moved.

Using the new GoogleApiClient

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final ScheduledExecutorService delayer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Location location;
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            // do something with location

        }
    };
    delayer.schedule(task, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```